# add summary information to a job results page in Jenkins/Hudson

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I have some jobs that deploy and run automated integration tests as part of our CI system.

These jobs are shell scripts that use ssh to deploy and then run commands on the systems to be tested. Then they gather the results in a tarball and archive it. One of the files in this tarball contains a nicely formatted summary that I would like to make visible without having to read through the console output or open a tarball.

- Is there a plugin for adding text to the job results page?
- Is there a plugin that will produce reports from archived job results?
- Is there an entirely more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

I would look at at [Summary Display Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Summary+Display+Plugin).

If you can output an XML from your build task, it will display it on the build page, using tables and other formatting.

Comment: I have used the [Summary Display Plugin][1] extensively for this purpose. In fact I have automated the creation of reports from property and csv file artifacts. See the following link for details https://github.com/imoutsatsos/jenkins-scriptlets/wiki/Other-Scriptlets


  [1]: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Summary+Display+Plugin

Comment: Summary Display Plugin doesn't work for jenkins version 2.138.4 +

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your results file into HTML format, the [HTML Publisher plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) will do the job for you.